# Speeding up a linq entitiy query

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework, linq

I currently have a query which not takes a long time and sometimes crashes because of the amount of data in the database.

Can someone notice anything i can do to help speed it up?

```
public IList<Report> GetReport(CmsEntities context, long manufacturerId, long? regionId, long? vehicleTypeId)
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var today = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
            var date1monthago = today.AddMonths(-1);
            var date2monthago = today.AddMonths(-2);
            var date3monthago = today.AddMonths(-3);
            var date4monthago = today.AddMonths(-4);
            var date5monthago = today.AddMonths(-5);
            var date6monthago = today.AddMonths(-6);
            today = TimeManager.EndOfDay(new DateTime(now.AddMonths(-1).Year, today.AddMonths(-1).Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(now.Year, today.AddMonths(-1).Month)));             
            var query = from item in context.Invoices
                         where item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.Select(x => x.ManufacturerId).Contains(manufacturerId)
                         && (item.InvoiceDate >= date6monthago && item.InvoiceDate <= today)
                         && (regionId.HasValue && regionId.Value > 0 ? item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.Select(x => x.RegionId).Contains(regionId.Value) : true)
                         && (item.InvType == "I" || item.InvType == null)
                         && (vehicleTypeId.HasValue && vehicleTypeId.Value > 0 ? item.Repair.Job.Vehicle.Model.VehicleTypes.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(vehicleTypeId.Value) : true)
                         select item;

            var query2 = from item in query
                         group item by new { item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop } into g
                         let manufJobs = query.Where(x => x.Repair.Job.Vehicle.Model.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId && x.Repair.Job.BodyshopId == g.Key.Bodyshop.Id)
                         let allJobs = query.Where(x => x.Repair.Job.BodyshopId == g.Key.Bodyshop.Id)
                         select new tReport
                         {                                     
    MonthSixManufJobTotal = manufJobs.Where(x => x.InvoiceDate.Month == date6monthago.Month && x.InvoiceDate.Year == date6monthago.Year).GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count(),
    MonthSixJobTotal = allJobs.Where(x => x.InvoiceDate.Month == date6monthago.Month && x.InvoiceDate.Year == date6monthago.Year).GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count(),

    MonthFiveManufJobTotal = manufJobs.Where(x => x.InvoiceDate.Month == date5monthago.Month && x.InvoiceDate.Year == date5monthago.Year).GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count(),
    MonthFiveJobTotal = allJobs.Where(x => x.InvoiceDate.Month == date5monthago.Month && x.InvoiceDate.Year == date5monthago.Year).GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count(),

    MonthFourManufJobTotal = manufJobs.Where(x => x.InvoiceDate.Month == date4monthago.Month && x.InvoiceDate.Year == date4monthago.Year).GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count(),
    MonthFourJobTotal = allJobs.Where(x => x.InvoiceDate.Month == date4monthago.Month && x.InvoiceDate.Year == date4monthago.Year).GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count(),

    MonthThreeManufJobTotal = manufJobs.Where(x => x.InvoiceDate.Month == date3monthago.Month && x.InvoiceDate.Year == date3monthago.Year).GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count(),
    MonthThreeJobTotal = allJobs.Where(x => x.InvoiceDate.Month == date3monthago.Month && x.InvoiceDate.Year == date3monthago.Year).GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count(),

    MonthTwoManufJobTotal = manufJobs.Where(x => x.InvoiceDate.Month == date2monthago.Month && x.InvoiceDate.Year == date2monthago.Year).GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count(),
    MonthTwoJobTotal = allJobs.Where(x => x.InvoiceDate.Month == date2monthago.Month && x.InvoiceDate.Year == date2monthago.Year).GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count(),

    MonthOneManufJobTotal = manufJobs.Where(x => x.InvoiceDate.Month == date1monthago.Month && x.InvoiceDate.Year == date1monthago.Year).GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count(),
    MonthOneJobTotal = allJobs.Where(x => x.InvoiceDate.Month == date1monthago.Month && x.InvoiceDate.Year == date1monthago.Year).GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count(),

    ManufTotal = manufJobs.GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count(),
    Total = allJobs.GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count(),

    PercentageOf = ((decimal)manufJobs.GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count() / (decimal)allJobs.GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count()) * 100
                         };

            return query2.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
        }
```

EDIT

```
var query = from item in context.Invoices.AsNoTracking()
                    where item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.Any(x => x.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId)
                    && (item.InvoiceDate >= date12monthago && item.InvoiceDate <= today)
                    && (item.InvType == "I" || item.InvType == null)
                    select item;

        if (regionId.HasValue && regionId.Value > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(item => item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.Select(x => x.RegionId).Contains(regionId.Value));
        }

        if (vehicleTypeId.HasValue && vehicleTypeId.Value > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(item => item.Repair.Job.Vehicle.Model.VehicleTypes.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(vehicleTypeId.Value));
        }


              var query2 = from item in hey
                     group item by new { item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop, item.InvoiceDate.Month } into m
                     select new TReport
                     {
                         Bodyshop = m.Key.Bodyshop.Name,
                         Bays = m.Key.Bodyshop.Bays,
                         Region = m.Key.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId).Region.Name,
                         BodyshopCode = m.Key.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId).BodyshopCode,
                         Total = m.Count(),
                         ManufTotal = m.Where(x => x.Repair.Job.Vehicle.Model.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId).Count(),
                         Totals = m.GroupBy(j => j.InvoiceDate.Month).Select(j => new TPercentReportInner
                         {
                             Month = j.Key,
                             ManufTotal = j.Where(x => x.Repair.Job.Vehicle.Model.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId).Count(),
                             AllTotal = j.Count()
                         })
                     };
```

Ive cut the query down. But even this is performing now worse than before?

Comment: What indexes are available on the table(s)?

Comment: Instead create a query that returns counts grouped by months, also make sure you have indexed InvoiceDate column.

Comment: i think at the moment only the id column on each table not the date column but i will try do that also

Comment: @Akash could you show an example of what you mean please

Comment: Set the queries AsNoTracking() since those are just retreivals & then further optimize based on @AkashKava answer.

Comment: That's a lot of linq. How does the query perform when doing it in plain tsql, you can always craft the query in sql, execute it with EF and have EF hydrate your entities, might be faster.  Also try profiling the generated sql to see where time is spent

Comment: Start by looking at the generated SQL, and analyze the query plan. Pretty sure you will be better of by hand-crafting a dedicated view yourself though.

Comment: I see you do this a lot : `item.Repair.Job`, wouldn't it be faster if you perform your queries directly on the job? Also I see you have 2 queries. sometimes lazy evaluation is a good thing but here it may be better if you do something like `var query2 = from item in query.Tolist()...`
but the best improvement I can think of is to create a view in the DB for your report and use scalar functions to retrieve the information. Entity framework can work with this.
Even this may be slow, you may end up doing skip/take anyway.
and of course having an indexed DB helps

Comment: Just create stored procedure\view with raw sql and not waste your time using EF for such complex queries. It's really not the best tool for such task. If you want to do that anyway, at least grab generated sql query, run it directly against database and look at query plan. This will lead you to solution much faster.

Comment: I think this line `MonthAllJobTotal = g.Count()` have performance impact. I am not fully sure about this, but you could give a try.

Comment: I'm putting this in a comment so as not to offend anyone, but I truly believe it to be a viable answer. In all honestly if you have complex queries in EF via Linq, I've found that its almost always easier and better performing to put the complex query into a traditional ADO.net class. Failing that, you can always put the query into a stored procedure, and then call the procedure from Entity. The goal basically is to remove the abstraction layer, as very often it is doing something it shouldn't for your particular use case, causing the performance issues you're experiencing.

Comment: @HBomb It may be easier (for you), and it might have a slight performance advantage, but it makes the code less maintainable to use ADO.net classes (unable to refactor, or refactoring the model no longer changes the ADO.net code).  Putting code into a stored procedure again has the same issues, but now adds complexity in maintaining version control and making sure syncronizing the versions (code and db) much more difficult for no performance gain at all.

Comment: @HBomb If all you want to do is write a raw SQL statement to be executed, you can do that in EF as well without needing to drop to ADO.net classes.

Comment: @Robert Fair points, but there are several tools out there (including CodeSmith, which I use) which generates the classes for me. I long ago modifed the templates so that the code they generate are extensible. Therefore when I need to make a change, I do it in the database, and regenerate the ADO classes with the push of a button. So I have all of the benefit of extensibility, automatic refactorability (using a DB first methodology) while maintaining the flexibility and performance of having direct access to the ADO classes underneath (which EF is built upon, BTW).

Comment: @Robert The only use case in which I am at a disadvantage is when you MUST develop your data model code first instead of DB first (which I never have to do, thankfully). Or if you work for a company that will not allow or invest in such a tool... but it wouldn't be hard to recreate quite frankly. You are just inspecting the DB through reflection at design time with a UI wizard attached and generating text output.

Comment: @Robert In all honesty, I have never understood why EF doesn't follow this pattern at least as a secondary option. It has always felt (to me) like it was trying to abstract away CONCEPTS instead of just boilerplate code. The problem of course being that understanding these concepts is necessary for optimization and debugging in situations such as the one presented by the question. As far as doing SQL within EF... well that kind of defeats the purpose, doesn't it? Not to mention the build time penalty for any decent sized data model in EF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start by removing the hardcoded optional conditionals from your query, which will allow the query optimizer to use different query plans based on the parameters you have, like:

```
var query = from item in context.Invoices.AsNoTracking()
            where item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.Select(x => x.ManufacturerId).Contains(manufacturerId)
            && (item.InvoiceDate >= date12monthago && item.InvoiceDate <= today)
            && (item.InvType == "I" || item.InvType == null)
            select item;

if (regionId.HasValue && regionId.Value > 0)
    query=query.Where(item=>item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.Select(x => x.RegionId).Contains(regionId.Value));

if (vehicleTypeId.HasValue && vehicleTypeId.Value > 0)
    query=query.Where(item=>item.Repair.Job.Vehicle.Model.VehicleTypes.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(vehicleTypeId.Value));

var query2 = from item in query
             group item by new { item.InvoiceDate.Month, item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop } into g
             select new TReport
             {
                 BodyshopId = g.Key.Bodyshop.Id,  
                 Month = g.Key.Month,
                 MonthAllJobTotal = g.Count()
             };

return query2.ToList();
```

You could also check to see if converting `.Select(x=>x.id).Contains(id)` or `.Any(x=>x.Id==id)` performs faster although I would think they would be similar in query plan and execution speed.  That would give you:

```
var query = from item in context.Invoices.AsNoTracking()
            where item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.Any(m=>m.ManufacturerId==manufacturerId)
            && (item.InvoiceDate >= date12monthago && item.InvoiceDate <= today)
            && (item.InvType == "I" || item.InvType == null)
            select item;

if (regionId.HasValue && regionId.Value > 0)
    query=query.Where(item=>item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.Any(m=>m.RegionId==regionId.Value));

if (vehicleTypeId.HasValue && vehicleTypeId.Value > 0)
    query=query.Where(item=>item.Repair.Job.Vehicle.Model.VehicleTypes.Any(v=>v.Id==vehicleTypeId.Value));

var query2 = from item in query
             group item by new { item.InvoiceDate.Month, item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop } into g
             select new TReport
             {
                 BodyshopId = g.Key.Bodyshop.Id,  
                 Month = g.Key.Month,
                 MonthAllJobTotal = g.Count()
             };

return query2.ToList();
```

Based on what you have, I would guess the `.AsNoTracking()` is doing very little for you, but it couldn't hurt.  It has a bigger effect when retrieving large numbers of entities which this doesn't appear to be doing.

I would then clean up and standardize your query by removing the hardcoded ManufacturerId as well, which would give you:

```
var query = from item in context.Invoices.AsNoTracking()
            where (item.InvoiceDate >= date12monthago && item.InvoiceDate <= today)
            && (item.InvType == "I" || item.InvType == null)
            select item;

if (manufacturerId.HasValue && manufacturerId.Value > 0)
    query=query.Where(item=>item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.Any(m=>m.ManufacturerId==manufacturerId));

if (regionId.HasValue && regionId.Value > 0)
    query=query.Where(item=>item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.Any(m=>m.RegionId==regionId.Value));

if (vehicleTypeId.HasValue && vehicleTypeId.Value > 0)
    query=query.Where(item=>item.Repair.Job.Vehicle.Model.VehicleTypes.Any(v=>v.Id==vehicleTypeId.Value));

var query2 = from item in query
             group item by new { item.InvoiceDate.Month, item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop } into g
             select new TReport
             {
                 BodyshopId = g.Key.Bodyshop.Id,  
                 Month = g.Key.Month,
                 MonthAllJobTotal = g.Count()
             };

return query2.ToList();
```

and then lastly, I would return an IQueryable instead of List so that if you don't need one or more columns they can be dropped from the final query as well like:

```
public IQueryable<Report> GetReport(CmsEntities context, long? manufacturerId, long? regionId, long? vehicleTypeId)
    {
{
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var today = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
        var date1monthago = today.AddMonths(-1);
        var date2monthago = today.AddMonths(-2);
        var date3monthago = today.AddMonths(-3);
        var date4monthago = today.AddMonths(-4);
        var date5monthago = today.AddMonths(-5);
        var date6monthago = today.AddMonths(-6);
        today = TimeManager.EndOfDay(new DateTime(now.AddMonths(-1).Year, today.AddMonths(-1).Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(now.Year, today.AddMonths(-1).Month)));             

    var query = from item in context.Invoices.AsNoTracking()
                where (item.InvoiceDate >= date12monthago && item.InvoiceDate <= today)
                && (item.InvType == "I" || item.InvType == null)
                select item;

    if (manufacturerId.HasValue && manufacturerId.Value > 0)
        query=query.Where(item=>item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.Any(m=>m.ManufacturerId==manufacturerId));

    if (regionId.HasValue && regionId.Value > 0)
        query=query.Where(item=>item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.Any(m=>m.RegionId==regionId.Value));

    if (vehicleTypeId.HasValue && vehicleTypeId.Value > 0)
        query=query.Where(item=>item.Repair.Job.Vehicle.Model.VehicleTypes.Any(v=>v.Id==vehicleTypeId.Value));

    var query2 = from item in query
                 group item by new { item.InvoiceDate.Month, item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop } into g
                 select new TReport
                 {
                     BodyshopId = g.Key.Bodyshop.Id,  
                     Month = g.Key.Month,
                     MonthAllJobTotal = g.Count()
                 };

    return query2;
}
```

Then I would break these apart and convert these to extension methods:

```
public static class MyExtensions 
{
    public static IQueryable<Invoice> Recent(this IQueryable<Invoice> context,long? manufacturerId=null,long? regionId=null,long? vehicleId=null)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var today = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
        var date1monthago = today.AddMonths(-1);
        var date2monthago = today.AddMonths(-2);
        var date3monthago = today.AddMonths(-3);
        var date4monthago = today.AddMonths(-4);
        var date5monthago = today.AddMonths(-5);
        var date6monthago = today.AddMonths(-6);
        today = TimeManager.EndOfDay(new DateTime(now.AddMonths(-1).Year, today.AddMonths(-1).Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(now.Year, today.AddMonths(-1).Month)));             

        var query = from item in context.Invoices.AsNoTracking()
                where (item.InvoiceDate >= date12monthago && item.InvoiceDate <= today)
                && (item.InvType == "I" || item.InvType == null)
                select item;

        if (manufacturerId.HasValue && manufacturerId.Value > 0)
            query=query.Where(item=>item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.Any(m=>m.ManufacturerId==manufacturerId));

        if (regionId.HasValue && regionId.Value > 0)
            query=query.Where(item=>item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.Any(m=>m.RegionId==regionId.Value));

        if (vehicleTypeId.HasValue && vehicleTypeId.Value > 0)
            query=query.Where(item=>item.Repair.Job.Vehicle.Model.VehicleTypes.Any(v=>v.Id==vehicleTypeId.Value));
    return query;
}
public static IQueryable<Report> ToReport(this IQueryable<Invoice> context)
{
    return (from item in query
                 group item by new { item.InvoiceDate.Month, item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop } into g
                 select new TReport
                 {
                     BodyshopId = g.Key.Bodyshop.Id,  
                     Month = g.Key.Month,
                     MonthAllJobTotal = g.Count()
                 });

}
}
```

Now you can do the following:

```
var reports=db.Invoices.Recent.ToReport();
```

or

```
var reports=db.Invoices.Recent(ManufacturerEnum.Toyota).ToReport();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could implementen paging to avoid materialize all results. I mean, you could implement Skip and Take linq methods.

Simple example based on your code:

```
public IList<Report> GetReport(CmsEntities context, long manufacturerId, long? regionId, long? vehicleTypeId, int pageSize, int currentPage)
        {

        //Code removed to simplify

        return  query2.Skip(pageSize * currentPage).Take(pageSize );

        }
```

Comment: Its something i will look to put forward at the moment they want to see everything but maybe just not possible

Answer (score 3):

First, some general SQL optimization tips:

**Before trying to do optimization, you should always profile**. 
Profiling has the combined advantage of giving you objective description or where you stand in terms of performance and giving hints of where you should start your optimization effort. And as a free added benefit, at the end of the day, you can justify your hard work to your management with clear objective numbers (or even performance graphs for powerpoint lovers).

As some suggests, you could try to optimize in two different ways:

- Optimize SQL plan (can be a time consuming task)

  1. Figure out what is the query in SQL.
  2. Run the query in SQL management studio or similar tool to define the best possible execution plan ( You may need to add indexes in the process). You should know from there if the optimization would be sufficient to match your performance criteria or not.
  3. Study current execution plan to check whether current query use most optimal indexes/keys, joins.
  4. Either modify code or use a intermediary SQL object (stored procedure or view) to make the linq to sql code use the optimized execution plan.
- Optimize the way code process data (less time consuming task)

  1. Caching (this can be in several ways, but the principle is to fetch the data you need and process it in the code). It is especially efficient when the query optimizer is not able to manage efficiently your query (old database version / engine not so good).
  2. Compile Link to SQL query. [Joe Albahari explains better than me.](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/speedinguplinqtosql.aspx)

Which approach you may favour first depends on merely on what performance gains you expect from it and what results you got from your profiling session.

By the look of the complexity of your linq to sql code, chances are that the generated sql query is sub optimal. On the other hand, linq in memory object management is quite fast compared to I/O with a remote SQL db.

Note that if you don't cache queries, it will fetch data each time. Caching could be done like that :

```
var allJobs = query.Where(x => x.Repair.Job.BodyshopId == g.Key.Bodyshop.Id).ToArray();
```

As a general rule of thumb, **K**eep **I**t **S**imple **S**tupid and your query is not. You may refactor it a little as it seems there is quite redundant code:

```
MonthSixManufJobTotal = manufJobs.Where(x => x.InvoiceDate.Month == date6monthago.Month && x.InvoiceDate.Year == date6monthago.Year).GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count(),
    MonthSixJobTotal = allJobs.Where(x => x.InvoiceDate.Month == date6monthago.Month && x.InvoiceDate.Year == date6monthago.Year).GroupBy(x => x.Repair.Job).Count(),
```

There is a quite widespread belief that by grouping all code in the same method (in a similar way as assembler code), you limit the number of method calls and then perform better in terms of performance. However the truth is counter-intuitive. Using the divide and conquer rule, a method chunked code will actually perform better in the end because it will be easier to maintain, to optimize, to enhance, to refactor. It was the whole point of software evolution from assembler to C#.

Comment: This should be the actual answer. 

How can you optimize code when you don't know where the bottleneck lies? I often see people spending a lot of time optimizing their code while the bottleneck isn't even where they expect it to be..

Answer (score 0):

(Note: I'm basing this on the queries in your edit)

There are a couple things you could potentially try. First, you could simplify the use of `.Select()` with `.Contains()` to use `.Any()` instead. This **could** result in a simpler query generated by EF, although it's hard to tell without using SQL Server Profiler or Visual Studio Debugger to see the actual SQL query. For example, change `.Select(x => x.ManufacturerId).Contains(manufacturerId)` to
`.Any(x => x.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId)`.

The second thing to try is to execute the first query against the SQL Server and process the second query in the application. EF [defers execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738633(v=vs.100).aspx) of a query until enumeration of the result occurs (e.g. `.ToList()` or `foreach`). So you could try `(from item in context ... select item).ToList()` on the first query which will cause the second query to execute in the application instead of on the SQL Server. This would help if the `group by` in the second query causes performance degradation if done by SQL Server instead of in the application itself.

However, if you try the second suggestion there may be a negative effect caused by the `item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop` grouping if it is a `virtual` navigation property because EF will have to get that object separately (as opposed to all in one query). This can be mitigated by changing the first query to `context.Invoices.AsNoTracking().Include("Repair.Job")` or `context.Invoices.AsNoTracking().Include(x => x.Repair.Job)` (the second option is not available older EF versions), and changing the second query to `group item by new { item.InvoiceDate.Month, item.Repair.Job.BodyshopId }`.

Comment: I think your first point is essential. The other point less so, because grouping isn't translated into a SQL `group by` but only into sorting (the actual grouping is already done in memory). The `Include` doesn't apply here, because the result is a projection. Another point is that `regionId.Value > 0 ?` etc. could be converted into `if (regionId.Value > 0) query = query.Where(item => item.Repair.Job....`, which reduces the number of decisions to be taken by the db engine.

Comment: @GertArnold The last part of this [blog](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/07/always-check-generated-sql-ef/) seems to imply that there are scenarios where the SQL Server provider for EF will generate SQL queries for the grouping rather than doing it in the application. I'm not sure that the two queries aren't combined and performed on the SQL server when there is no enumeration between the queries using `.ToList()`. To your second point, conditionally chaining in the `.Where()` clauses only as needed should help query generation. Profiling the generated SQL would be the only way to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you break it down into smaller bit size parts.  Get the initial data into separate lists and then maybe sew them together.

You can get a lot of milage into ToDictionary and ToLookup extensions.

I bet if you took a look at the SQL you are sending to the database it would be insane.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the elimination of the unnecessary `where` conditions, I'll put my bet on the `group by` clause.

You are including `item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop` as one of the grouping fields. 
Anytime you use something like this, **EF** will generate a SQL `GROUP BY` clause including **all** the fields from the corresponding table. I don't know how many columns do you have in the db table that corresponds to your `Bodyshop` entity, but in any case using it this way most probably will not allow creating a good SQL execution plan.

I would suggest you trying the following equivalent of your cut down query:

```
var query = context.Invoices.AsNoTracking().Where(item =>
    (item.InvType == "I" || item.InvType == null) &&
    (item.InvoiceDate >= date12monthago && item.InvoiceDate <= today));

if (regionId.HasValue && regionId.Value > 0)
    query = query.Where(item =>
        item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.Any(source =>
            source.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId && source.RegionId == regionId.Value));
else
    query = query.Where(item => 
        item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop.Manufacturer2Bodyshop.Any(source => 
            source.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId));

if (vehicleTypeId.HasValue && vehicleTypeId.Value > 0)
    query = query.Where(item =>
        item.Repair.Job.Vehicle.Model.VehicleTypes.Any(vehicleType => 
            vehicleType.Id == vehicleTypeId.Value);

var query2 = query
    .GroupBy(item => new { Month = item.InvoiceDate.Month, BodyshopId = item.Repair.Job.Bodyshop.Id })
    .Select(g => new TReport { BodyshopId = g.Key.BodyshopId, Month = g.Key.Month, MonthAllJobTotal = g.Count() });

var result = query2.ToList();
```